# Core Dump usando malloc() para um vetor de struct

Tags: c, ponteiro

Estou fazendo um programa em C que utiliza aritmética de ponteiros, então eu criei um vetor e um ponteiro do tipo struct. O vetor armazena as informações e o ponteiro aponta para o primeiro endereço do vetor, assim:

```
Dados produto[n], *pont;

pont = &produto[0];
```

depois disso eu faço malloc:

```
pont = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(produto));
```

Mas quando eu chego no free, no final do código:

```
free(pont);
```

o programa dá o seguinte erro:

*free(): invalide pointer

signal: aborted (core dumped)*

Porém, esse erro só acontece se eu acessar alguma das opções do menu, caso eu só inicie o programa e entre na opção 5(sair) ele faz o free correto e não retorna nenhum erro.

Código inteiro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Dados{
    char Nome[15];
    int Quantidade;
    int Mes;
    char Comprador[10];
}Dados;



int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese_Brazil");
    int n=6, i, z, lido, j, mes, mes_parada, soma, opcao;
    char cliente[10], nome_produto[15];



    /*printf("Quantos produtos você quer cadastrar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);*/
    Dados produto[n], *pont;

    pont = &produto[0];

    pont = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(produto));


    printf("\n");

    strcpy(produto[0].Nome, "Nescau");
    strcpy(produto[1].Nome, "Nescau");
    strcpy(produto[2].Nome, "Nescau");
    strcpy(produto[3].Nome, "Arroz");
    strcpy(produto[4].Nome, "Feijao");
    strcpy(produto[5].Nome, "Nescau");

    strcpy(produto[0].Comprador, "Shibata");
    strcpy(produto[1].Comprador, "Shibata");
    strcpy(produto[2].Comprador, "Shibata");
    strcpy(produto[3].Comprador, "Extra");
    strcpy(produto[4].Comprador, "Extra");
    strcpy(produto[5].Comprador, "Extra");

    produto[0].Mes=1;
    produto[1].Mes=2;
    produto[2].Mes=2;
    produto[3].Mes=1;
    produto[4].Mes=4;
    produto[5].Mes=5;

    produto[0].Quantidade=1;
    produto[1].Quantidade=2;
    produto[2].Quantidade=2;
    produto[3].Quantidade=1;
    produto[4].Quantidade=4;
    produto[5].Quantidade=5;



    /*for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        printf("\nProduto: ");
        fgets(produto[i].Nome, sizeof(produto[i].Nome), stdin);
        printf("\nQuantidade: ");
        scanf("%d", &produto[i].Quantidade);
        fflush(stdin);
        do{
            printf("\nMês: ");
            scanf("%d", &mes);
            fflush(stdin);
            if(mes=>1 && mes=<12){
                produto[i].Mes==mes;
                mes_parada = 1;
            }else{
                printf("Mês inválido, insira um mês válido.\n")
                mes_parada =0;
            }
        }while(mes_parada!= 1);


        printf("\nComprador: ");
        fgets(produto[i].Comprador, sizeof(produto[i].Comprador), stdin);
    }*/

    system("clear||cls");


    do{
        printf("\n\n-------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n1) Total de vendas num dado mês(todos produtos).");
        printf("\n2) Total de vendas de um determinado produto num dado mês para um determinado cliente");
        printf("\n3) Total de vendas de cada produto.");
        printf("\n4) Total vendido para cada cliente.");
        printf("\n5) Fim.");

        printf("\n\nO que deseja fazer: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        fflush(stdin);


        switch(opcao){
            case 1:
                soma = 0;

                printf("Qual mês gostaria de ver: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                scanf("%d", &mes);
                fflush(stdin);
                if(mes>=1 && mes<=12){

                }else{
                    system("clear||cls");
                    printf("Mês inválido.\n");
                    system("pause");
                    system("clear||cls");
                    break;
                }


                for(pont = &produto[0]; pont<&produto[n]; pont++){
                    if(pont->Mes==mes){
                        soma = soma + pont->Quantidade;
                    }
                }

                if(soma==0){
                    printf("Não foram encontradas vendas nesse mês.\n");
                }else{
                    printf("No mês %d a quantidade total de produtos vendidos foram: %d\n\n", mes, soma);
                }
                system("pause");
                system("clear||cls");
            break;

            case 2://arrumar essa funcao
                soma = 0;

                printf("Qual mês gostaria de ver: ");
                scanf("%d", &mes);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("Qual cliente gostaria de ver: ");
                fgets(cliente, 10, stdin);
                cliente[strcspn(cliente, "\n")] = 0;

                printf("Qual produto gostaria de ver: ");
                fgets(nome_produto, 10, stdin);
                nome_produto[strcspn(nome_produto, "\n")] = 0;

                for(pont=&produto[0];pont<&produto[n];pont++){
                    if(pont->Mes==mes && strcmp(nome_produto, pont->Nome)==0 && strcmp(cliente, pont->Comprador)==0){
                        soma = soma + pont->Quantidade;
                    }
                }
                if(soma==0){
                    printf("Não foram encontradas vendas para as informções dadas.\n");
                }else{
                    printf("Foram vendidos %d unidade(s) de %s, para o cliente %s no mês %d", soma, nome_produto, cliente, mes);
                }




                system("pause");
                system("clear||cls");
            break;

            case 3:

                for(pont=&produto[0], i=0; pont<&produto[n]; pont++, i++){
                    lido=0;

                    for(z=0; z<i; z++){

                        if(strcmp(produto[i].Nome, produto[z].Nome)==0){
                            lido=1;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if(lido==1){
                        continue;
                    }
                    soma=0;

                    printf("\n***********%s***********", pont->Nome);

                    for(j=0; j<n; j++){
                        if(strcmp(produto[j].Nome, pont->Nome)==0){
                            printf("\nNo mês %d, a quantidade vendida foi: %d.", produto[j].Mes, produto[j].Quantidade);
                            soma= soma + produto[j].Quantidade;
                        }
                    }
                printf("\nO total de venda de %s foi: %d.\n", pont->Nome, soma);
                }

            printf("\n");
            break;

            case 4:
            system("clear||cls");

            for(pont=&produto[0], i=0; pont<&produto[n]; pont++, i++){
                lido=0;

                for(z=0; z<i; z++){

                    if(strcmp(produto[i].Comprador, produto[z].Comprador)==0){
                        lido=1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(lido==1){
                    continue;
                }
                soma=0;

                for(j=0; j<n; j++){
                    if(strcmp(produto[j].Comprador, pont->Comprador)==0){

                        soma= soma + produto[j].Quantidade;
                    }
                }

                printf("\nO cliente %s comprou, ao total: %d produtos.", pont->Comprador, soma);

                printf("\n");
            }

            break;

            case 5:
                system("clear||cls");
                printf("Programa finalizado com sucesso!\n\n");
            break;

            default:
                system("clear||cls");
                printf("Erro!\n");

        }
    }while(opcao!=5);

    free(pont);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está no conceito do uso de ponteiros.

A confusão toda ocorre neste trecho:

```c
Dados produto[n], *pont;
pont = &produto[0];
pont = (Dados *)malloc(sizeof(produto));
```

Tu já tem a memória alocada quando definiu a variável produto. Na segunda linha o ponteiro vai apontar para o endereço da primeira posição do vetor produto. Então o ponteiro não está alocando memória dinamicamente. Este uso é comum quando se deseja passar parâmetros por referência, ou retornar um vetor em uma função. Este tipo de ponteiro não deve ser liberado (pois ele não alocou memória).

Na linha seguinte tu está alocando memória dinamicamente para o espaço de 1 produto (o que não faz muito sentido) se tu deseja apontar para a memória que já está alocada.

É importante que tu veja o que deseja fazer com o ponteiro, se quer criar um vetor com tamanho dinâmico, ou simplesmente usar ele para ter a referência do endereço de um vetor já criado. Ponteiros não são tão simples, é preciso usá-los com cuidado.

Pode usar os recursos de depuração (debug) da IDE que estiver utilizando para acompanhar em tempo real como estes estão sendo alocados.

Sugiro fazer um outro código menor e mais simples para tentar reproduzir o problema isoladamente, assim é mais fácil de entender o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Creio que eu entendi, e tenha consertado o código.  Mudei de **produto[n]** para ***produto**, fiz o malloc para **produto**, igual estava antes para o **pont**, e fiz um _free(produto)_. Resolveu meu problema, por enquanto, não sei se fiz corretamente, mas está funcionando!!

Comment: Dados *produto, *pont;   produto  = (Dados *)malloc(n*sizeof(Dados)); pont = &produto[0]

Answer (score 0):

Seu programa tem vários problemas relacionados ao modo como está tratando alocação de memória e outras coisas. Para não me afastar do tópico vou escrever sobre a questão que levantou, e ao final vou deixar umas notas sobre o programa em si.

```
    /*printf("Quantos produtos você quer cadastrar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    fflush(stdin);*/
    Dados produto[n], *pont;
```

Isso é o início de `main()` em seu código. Embora exista um troço chamado `VLA` em `C` que permite declarar arrays como de tamanho variável como em `Dados produto[n]` acho que deve esquecer isso por hora. E aqui de todo modo vai alocar memória para um vetor de produtos usando `malloc()` e a idéia desse VLA seria alocar na declaração e não usar `malloc()/free()`, alocando o vetor no stack.
O compilador deve ter reclamado já quando compilou seu programa. Veja o que o compilador da Microsoft diz sobre a declaração de produto (26) e o `malloc()` na linha 30:

```
(26): error C2057: expected constant expression
(26): error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
(26): error C2133: 'produto': unknown size
(30): warning C4034: sizeof returns 0
```

`gcc` e `clang`, os outros compiladores comuns, diriam algo similar. Sempre leia e procure entender essas mensagens do seu compilador. Use `Wall` no `gcc` e `/W3` ao menos no MSVC ao compilar seus programas.

EM RESUMO:

- declare um tamanho fixo --- conhecido em tempo de compilação --- para o vetor
- faça a conta no próprio `malloc()` para determinar o tamanho da área.

**Vou mostrar um exemplos a seguir**

#### Escrevendo em torno dos dados

Está um pouco confuso o modo como declarou: o que você quer é um cadastro de produtos, de `n` produtos. Precisa de mais um nível de composição em seu programa, algo como:

```
typedef struct
{
    char Nome[15];
    int  Quantidade;
    int  Mes;
    char Comprador[10];

}   Produto; // um produto

typedef struct
{
    int      cap; // quantos cabem
    int      N;   // quantos tem agora
    Produto* prd; // o vetor de produtos

}   Cadastro; // 1 cadastro
```

Esse é o conceito de encapsulamento, como em java, Python ou C++, e facilita muito as coisas, porque pode declarar suas funções em termos mais próximos do real, coisas como

```
    Cadastro* cria_cad(int);
    Cadastro* apaga_cad(Cadastro* cad);
```

E criar e destruir um cadastro para `n=3000` produtos fica simples como

```
Cadastro* um_teste = cria_cad(3000);
um = apaga_cad(um_teste);
```

Uma implementação de exemplo

```
Cadastro* cria_cad(int qtd)
{
    Cadastro* C = (Cadastro*)malloc(sizeof(Cadastro));
    if (C == NULL) return NULL;
    // dentro do cadastro cria o vetor de produto
    C->prd = (Produto*)malloc(qtd * sizeof(Produto));
    C->N        = 0;
    C->cap = qtd;
    return C;
};
```

Assim fica claro quantos produtos cabem no cadastro, quantos tem agora e o vetor deles. Aí tem uma decisão: em muitos casos é melhor ter um vetor de ponteiros para `Produto` do que um vetor de `Produto`. Vou deixar como você escreveu.

```
Cadastro* apaga_cad(Cadastro* cad)
{ 
    free(cad);
    return NULL;
}
```

Deixando isso separado você se defende de casos de mudança do layout do cadastro, por exemplo se precisar mudar o `Produto` para alocar memória: apagar fica mais complicado. Deixando criar e apagar em funções separadas fica mais fácil. Retornar `NULL` ao apagar é uma chance de invalidar o ponteiro na mesma linha, o que é mais seguro do que deixar para depois e ficar apontando para uma área liberada. Veja no exemplo ao final. Em C++ por exemplo pode até declarar `[[nodiscard]]` para essa função para obrigar o programa a usar o retorno. `C` não tem esse recurso.

E graças ao encapsulamento inserir um produto pode ser muito mais simples:

```
int      insere_cad(Produto* prd, Cadastro* cad)
    { 
    if (prd == NULL) return -1;
    if (cad == NULL) return -2;
    if (cad->N >= cad->cap) return -3; // cheio
    cad->prd[cad->N] = *prd; // copia
    cad->N += 1;  // conta esse
    return 0;
};
```

Assim o encapsulamento permite que se mude o layout de `Produto` sem mexer nas definições.

#### Criando dados de teste

Você escreveu

```
    printf("\n");

    strcpy(produto[0].Nome, "Nescau");
    strcpy(produto[1].Nome, "Nescau");
    // ...
    strcpy(produto[0].Comprador, "Shibata");
    strcpy(produto[1].Comprador, "Shibata");
    // ...
    produto[0].Mes=1;
    produto[1].Mes=2;
    //...
    produto[0].Quantidade=1;
    produto[1].Quantidade=2;
    produto[2].Quantidade=2;
    //...
```

E já perdeu a paciência com 10 produtos e começou a repetir nomes. E se fossem 10.000?

Em geral para criar um produto usando o mesmo lance de encapsulamento se escreve uma função --- muitas vezes chamada de *factory function* ou *generator* --- que devolve um `Produto` preenchido e numerado, e assim se começa a testar as funções em minutos...

#### Exemplo

```
Produto* f_produto()
{
    static int id = 1;
    Produto* pr = (Produto*)malloc(sizeof(Produto));
    if (pr == NULL) return NULL;
    sprintf(pr->Nome, "Produto %06d\0", id);
    sprintf(pr->Comprador, "Cmp%06d\0", id);
    id += 1;
    pr->Mes = 1 + rand() % 12;
    pr->Quantidade = 20 + rand() % 81; // 20..100
    return pr;
}
```

Algo assim sempre é prático porque testar um programa interativo é um inferno, e retornando um ponteiro para um registro NUMERADO indica que é fácil de testar e a memória pode ser liberada logo em seguida.

### um exemplo completo

#### Saída do exemplo

```
cria cadastro com 3000 produtos
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
    Final com 3000 produtos
    Primeiro produto:     Produto 000001  Cmp000001    6    100
      Ultimo produto:     Produto 003000  Cmp003000    5     75
```

#### codigo do exemplo

Esse programa:

- Cria um cadastro de 3000 itens
- Preenche com produtos numerados, usando a tal factory function
- mostra um `.` a cada 50 produtos
- pula uma linha a cada 500 produtos
- mostra o primeiro e o último produto
- apaga tudo

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char Nome[15];
    int  Quantidade;
    int  Mes;
    char Comprador[10];

}   Produto; // um produto

typedef struct
{
    int      cap; // quantos cabem
    int      N;   // quantos tem agora
    Produto* prd; // o vetor de produtos

}   Cadastro; // 1 cadastro

Cadastro* cria_cad(int);
Cadastro* apaga_cad(Cadastro*);
int       insere_cad(Produto*,Cadastro*);

Produto* f_produto(); // fabrica de produto
void     mostra_produto(Produto*);


int main(void)
{
    const int total   = 3000;
    Cadastro* tst_cad = cria_cad(total);
    Produto*  p        = f_produto();
    printf("cria e preenche cadastro com %d produtos\n", total);
    int       n        = 1;
    while (insere_cad(p, tst_cad) == 0)
    {
        free(p);  // apaga o produto, ja foi copiado
        if (n % 50 == 0) printf(".");
        if (n % 500 == 0) printf("\n");
        n += 1;
        p = f_produto(); // fabrica outro
    }
    printf(
        "\n\
    Final com %d produtos\n\
    Primeiro produto:    ",
        tst_cad->N);
    mostra_produto(&tst_cad->prd[0]);
    printf("      Ultimo produto:    ");
    mostra_produto( &tst_cad->prd[tst_cad->N-1] );

    tst_cad = apaga_cad(tst_cad);
    return 0;
}

Cadastro* apaga_cad(Cadastro* cad)
{ 
    free(cad);
    return NULL;
}

Cadastro* cria_cad(int qtd)
{
    Cadastro* C = (Cadastro*)malloc(sizeof(Cadastro));
    if (C == NULL) return NULL;
    // dentro do cadastro cria o vetor de produto
    C->prd = (Produto*)malloc(qtd * sizeof(Produto));
    C->N        = 0;
    C->cap = qtd;
    return C;
};

Produto* f_produto()
{
    static int id = 1;
    Produto* pr = (Produto*)malloc(sizeof(Produto));
    if (pr == NULL) return NULL;
    sprintf(pr->Nome, "Produto %06d\0", id);
    sprintf(pr->Comprador, "Cmp%06d\0", id);
    id += 1;
    pr->Mes = 1 + rand() % 12;
    pr->Quantidade = 20 + rand() % 81; // 20..100
    return pr;
}

int      insere_cad(Produto* prd, Cadastro* cad)
    { 
    if (prd == NULL) return -1;
    if (cad == NULL) return -2;
    if (cad->N >= cad->cap) return -3; // cheio
    cad->prd[cad->N] = *prd; // copia
    cad->N += 1;  // conta esse
    return 0;
};

void mostra_produto(Produto* prd)
{
    printf("%15s %10s   %2d %6d\n", prd->Nome, prd->Comprador, prd->Mes,
           prd->Quantidade);
}
```

#### Sobre seu programa

[sei que não perguntou isso, mas seguem uns palpites sobre seu programa ]

- esse locale `Portuguese_Brazil` provavelmente está errado. TESTE o retorno. Em geral use "pt_BR" ou "pt_BR.utf-8" que estão no padrão.
- use valores constantes para os tamanhos de vetores
- declare uma variável por linha e inicialize todas
- não use `fflush()` na entrada. Nem está definido isso e pode não funcionar.
- não use `system()` nunca. Não vai aprender nada.
- declare as variáveis de controle do loop DENTRO do loop
- entenda que um `printf()` de 7 linhas é muito mais esperto que 7 `printf()` de uma linha. E se vai apenas mostrar algo na tela use `puts()` que é muito mais rápido.
- se tem um menu use uma função que mostra o menu e retorna a opção.